# how to copy a css block from chrome styles panel?

Tags: css, google-chrome

sometimes I make small modifications to a website, and then I want to copy the result. 
for instance in the image below, i want to copy all the block at once and not line by line, is there an option in chrome to do that? just wondering.

[image]

Comment: You can copy and paste it similar to the way that you use word or even text on a browser

Comment: Just select, copy and paste, like you would do anywhere else

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the block and copy like on a text editor.

1. You can do a right click after select and click on copy.
2. <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the selection.

You can only copy the related parts, so the color previews and arrows are not on the clipboard after copy. You can only copy the code!

Comment: thanks, I tried to do it like that previously and failed, now it works.